# How do I set a recurring event on every 8th day of the month?

Tags: 2007, calendar

I want to create a recurring event in a calendar to be every 8th weekday of the month. I see that the options for this include first, second, third, fourth and last. It kind of just doesn't make sense that they don't give you the option to go further than that.

Is this possible?

Comment: I was going to suggest you sync the calendar with Outlook and set up the recurring meeting from there, but it behaves the same way. Odd.

Comment: Yeah, it looks that they left it out by design! Is it we might be missing some sort of mathematics here?

Comment: It is not rare at all if you include monthly reporting cycles which often require actions on multiple days including day 6, day 7, day 8 and beyond as well as later on in the month for preparation of end of month reporting. I work for one of the largest worldwide corporations and all of our divisions have similar requirements...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in either 2007 or 2010. I suspect that its nothing more than an oversight :-

- For the Sunday through Saturday options then only 1/2/3/4 and last options make sense (there are never going to be 8 Mondays in a month for example)
- For the day option you might as well use "Day X of every Y month(s)"
- Only for the weekday/weekend day does anything > 4 make sense.

However - in SharePoint 2003 you only had the option of Sun > Sat - so by the time these were added in 2007 either no-one revisited the "First/Second...." dropdown or decided that the effort to change the available options depending on if you choose day/weekday etc wasn't worth the effort for edge cases like "Repeat on the 8th weekday of the month" - which I would think is pretty rare.

Comment: Well in my company, they actually want to set meetings every 10th business day of the month. I don't know exactly why, but I was asked this question. I agree that it's not that common.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is as rare as we are made to believe.  I must deliver documents to the customer on the X working day of the month.  This is because if we say the X day of the month then sometimes they land on the weekend.  If you are able to edit the source code then you could add the additional dates.  I unfortunately cannot edit my source code so I am still looking for a solution.